# Max and min values of H, S and B in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hsb

What are the minimum and maximum values of Hue, Staturation and Brightnest when they are modified through AdjustColor class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the manual, the ranges are listed below each property.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/AdjustColor.html

For reference in case docs go down:

- Hue: -180 to 180
- Contrast: -100 to 100
- Saturation: -100 to 100

Comment: The problem is that there is no documented properties https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0oNOpRt01j6N2taT2s0ODRWNTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There are, just check Runtimes at the top and select Flash Player 9 (or above).

Comment: I had to check "Products", but I found them, 10x :)